# glib make error: syntax error near unexpected token `(‘

Tags: embedded, glib, open-source

I am trying to install glib from source code on an embedded linux platform.

I am getting the following error on doing ‘make’:

> Make[4]: Entering directory ‘/glib-2.55.0/gobject’
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(‘
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo “ CCLD  “ libgobject-2.0.la;/bin/sh
>   ../libtool –silent –tag=CC  --mode=link gcc –Wall –Wstr’
>
> Makefile: 1170: recipe for target ‘libgobject-2.0.la’ failed

line 1169 and 1170 of the Makefile are these:

1169:

```
libgobject-2.0.la: $(libgobject_2_0_la_OBJECTS)   
      $(libgobject_2_0_la_DEPENDENCIES) 
      $(EXTRA_libgobject_2_0_la_DEPENDENCIES)
```

1170:

```
$(AM_V_CCLD) $(libgobject_2_0_la_LINK) -rpath $(libdir) 
      $(libgobject_2_0_la_OBJECTS) $(libgobject_2_0_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
```

In the Makefile line 1169 is in a single line and line 1170 is in another separate single line. Here due to formatting constraints I had to split it.

When I join 1169 and 1170, I get a different error which is:

> *** No rule to make target '@echo', needed by 'libobject-2.0.la'. Stop.

What is causing this error? Do I have to set some environment variable? I am especially confused because it says line 0.
How do I resolve this error?

Comment: line zero is when you do `sh -c` *something* and *something* is a syntax error etc.   cause is some sort of syntax error in the makefile, near line 1170

Comment: I have updated my post with the details of the line 1169 and 1170.

Comment: You are putting the wrong `Makefile` into your question.  Note what directory recursive `make` says that it is in.

Comment: @JdeBP : You are right. I have corrected the Makefile details and added some more information. I'll greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: See if `make -p` tells you anything useful - in particular the values of the make variables `AM_V_CCLD`, `libgobject_2_0_la_LINK`, `libdir`, `libgobject_2_0_la_OBJECTS`, `libgobject_2_0_la_LIBADD` and `LIBS`; also if you used GNU configure, post the config arguments you used

Comment: @MurrayJensen : I did "make -p" and after that "make". Now the make was successful and the error is gone. Don't know how it worked. I did not do any changes in the Makefile. What happened here?

Comment: could be anything ... e.g. embedded system running out of memory; note that `make -p` simply executes a normal make but prints the values of all make variables before updating any targets - so you basically ran make two more times.